# How to execute some code the first time a Julia function is called?

Tags: julia

I have a specific use case where I want a function to basically provide a warning the first time it is called to tell the user some info. Other than using a global counter and keeping track of the number of times the function is called, I am not sure how I can check this. Any ideas on specific Julia syntax that would allow me to check if the function is being called for the first time?

Comment: I think you have the right idea, at some level there has to be a conditional check. I'd like to move the check outside the function but that requires planning a specific spot in your code to call the function for the first time, which I'm guessing is not your intent. Really thinking outside the box, generated functions  do stuff at compile-time with argument types, and compilation only happens at first method call, but that's not a function per se and you probably want to use runtime values.

Comment: Alternatively you can write a macro which would create such a tracker. It would be similar to Memoize.jl (but just instead of keeping track of return values it would keep track of the call counter).

Comment: A higher order function like the Python decorator pattern can also create a tracker generically, but now that I really think about it, an inner method can be unwieldy. Its type is verbose like anonymous functions and parametric closures, and I have no idea how to add such a method to a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some ideas for how to do this when you have the option of rewriting the function body.  <strike>All of these could also be realized by writing a rather simple macro performing the respective transformation.</strike> OK, it's not so trivial if you want to get top-level and local definitions working right.

### (Non-)option 1

Conceptually, you could do this with a generated function, and it will work mostly when you try it out:

```
julia> @generated function dostuff(x)
           @warn "You really shouldn't do stuff!"
           return :(2x + 1)
       end
dostuff (generic function with 1 method)

julia> dostuff(1)
┌ Warning: You really shouldn't do stuff!
└ @ Main REPL[1]:2
3

julia> dostuff(1)
3
```

But: **don't**.  The compiler is free to choose when to call the "generator", and to quote [the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions): **it is undefined exactly when, how often or how many times these side-effects will occur**.  Not a good idea.

Additionally, it is questionable whether `@warn` will use a printing function that is allowed within a generated function.  In earlier Julias, using `println` instead of `Core.println` sometimes errored in generated functions, because the former modified the event loop.

### Option 2

So for something better.  Instead of your idea with a global counter, you can do something similar by defining the function as a closure of a let-bound variable:

```
julia> let isfirstcall = Threads.Atomic{Bool}(true)
           global function dostuff(x) 
               if Threads.atomic_xchg!(isfirstcall, false)
                   @warn "You really shouldn't do stuff!"
               end
               return 2x + 1
           end
       end
dostuff (generic function with 1 method)

julia> dostuff(1)
┌ Warning: You really shouldn't do stuff!
└ @ Main REPL[16]:4
3

julia> dostuff(1)
3

julia> isfirstcall
ERROR: UndefVarError: isfirstcall not defined
```

I have here chosen to use atomics just for the fun of `atomic_xchg!`, but if threading is not an issue, a plain boolean will be fine, too.

### Option 3

Also, while avoidable, a global variable isn't too bad if you do it right.  Which means: make it a `const` `Ref`.  And (optionally, but recommended in this case), use a `var` string to give it a name not usually accessible to the user:

```
julia> const var"##isfirstcall" = Ref(true)

julia> function dostuff(x)
           if var"##isfirstcall"[]
               @warn "You really shouldn't do stuff!"
               var"##isfirstcall"[] = false
           end
           return 2x + 1
       end
dostuff (generic function with 1 method)

julia> dostuff(1)
┌ Warning: You really shouldn't do stuff!
└ @ Main REPL[22]:3
3

julia> dostuff(1)
3
```

Comment: This is very helpful. It is also worth noting that in this case, the @ warn and @ info macros have a maxlog attribute you can set 1 which prevents multiple Print-outs.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `maxlog` feature of the logging macros:

```
julia> function warnfirst(x, y)
           @warn "This is the first time you called this" maxlog=1
           return 2x + y
       end
warnfirst (generic function with 1 method)

julia> warnfirst(1, 2)
┌ Warning: This is the first time you called this
└ @ Main REPL[1]:2
4

julia> warnfirst(1, 2)
4

julia> warnfirst(1.0, 2.0)   # what about different specializations?
4.0
```